# Spring data with Hibernate Jpa does not commit on Weblogic

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, weblogic12c

I was able to have this configuration working on glassfish but it does not work/commit on Weblogic 12c.

I don't have any exception but It does not commit the changes on the database.

Does someone have a working configuration.

My Pom dependencies follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>10.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My spring configuration file follows:

```
<beans>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ericsson.noc"/>
<context:annotation-config />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.ericsson.noc" />   

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc.ds"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" /> 


<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    <property name="prepareConnection" value="false" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="oracle" />
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ericsson.noc" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml" />
</bean>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

My persistence.xml callend jpa-persistence.xml follows:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="oracle" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc.ds</jta-data-source> 
<class>xxx.yyy.Entity</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes/>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true"/>  
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"  value="jta"/>   
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: add the code that performs the save / update

Comment: @Transactional
    public void saveRole(String abbreviation, String description)throws BusinessException{             AmmRole ammRole = new AmmRole();
            ammRole.setAbbreviation(abbreviation);
            ammRole.setDescription(description);
            ammRole.setSysRole("N");
            ammRole = ammRoleRepository.save(ammRole);} where ammRoleRepository is a spring-data repository and Transactional is of type org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see where you configure the TransactionManager for Spring to use. So one idea is that maybe Spring and Hibernate use different TransactionManagers and therefore Spring committing a transaction has no effect on Hibernate.

So the things to do would be:

- Include a `PlatformTransactionManager` in your Spring configuration and see if this fixes the problem
- If it doesn't inspect the `ApplicationContext` and Hibernate to see if they reference the same `TransactionManager`

See also: https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/

Comment: Hi, <tx:jta-transaction-manager/> defines a jta transaction manager.. I fixed this issue and it was a missconfiguration on the hibernate side.. the spring part was ok..

Comment: Old post, i know...but any change you recall and have an idea what kind of misconfig issue it was? I'm having the same symptons and trying to get ideas of what to look at. Thanks.